# how to fix the problem of downloading fasttext-model300?

Tags: text-mining, gensim, similarity, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I'm using windows 10 and python 3.3. I tried to download fasttext_model300 to calculate soft cosine similarity between documents, but when I run my python file, it stops after arriving at this statement:

```
fasttext_model300 = api.load('fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300')
```

There are no errors or not responding, It just stops without any reaction.

Does anybody know why it happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against using the `gensim` `api.load()` functionality. It dynamically runs new, unversioned source code from remote servers – which is opaque in its operations & suboptimal for maintaining a secure local configuration, or debugging any issues which occur.

Instead, find the actual exact data files you trust and download them as plain data. Then, use specific library operations, like the `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` method, so instantiate exactly the model you need, using precise local-file paths you understand.

Following those steps may make it clearer what, if anything, is going wrong. If it doesn't, try also enabling logging at the INFO level to gather more information about what progress is made before failure (and add any new details as a comment or to your question).

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m gensim.downloader --download fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300
```

Try using this. Source : https://awesomeopensource.com/project/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data